# how can I setup LD_LIBRARY_PATH for apache daemon?

Tags: php, c++, apache

I have multiple versions of gcc `4.1.2` and `4.9.1` installed as `g++4.9`.
The old version had really old libstdc++ and was always failing with requiring `libgcc` errors. I fixed that by adding
`export LD_LIBARY_PATH=/home/naveen/gcc4.9/lib: /home/naveen/gcc4.9/lib64` to all users. I even set this in `/etc/bashrc` and did `. /etc/bashrc` as root.
Now I am running a c++ code using php but the code always fails with the same `libgcc errors` i was seeing from console. I can see that the apache is being controlled by user daemon.
How can I fix this so that apache and php use the modified ld_library_paths?

Answer (score 1):

Edit the scripts that actually start httpd and export the variables there.

Comment: you mean httpd.conf?

Comment: No. The scripts. That start it.

Comment: sorry if naive. i installed from source. i start using apachetcl start. so ..../bin/apachetcl?

Comment: You start httpd as a user every time the machine restarts?

Comment: no. but so happens that haven't restarted the machine since install. does this mean it will need a machine reboot to work?

Comment: Have you figured out how your system's boot process works yet?

Comment: no. will that be needed? No conf, envvars settings would work as of now. the thing is i can't reboot now as some other setups are also in progress.

Comment: You need to sit down with your sysadmin and tell them that you need this change implemented, and then ask them how you should restart httpd such that this variable will always be set.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60717/discussion-between-naveen-sharma-and-ignacio-vazquez-abrams).